# Prove that $f\ast g$ is defined a.e., integrable, and such that $∥f\ast g∥_1 ≤ ∥f∥_1 · ∥g∥_1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be $L_1$-functions. Set $h(x) = \int_\mathbb{R}f (x − y)g(y) \, dm(y).$
Prove that $h(x)$ is defined a.e., $h ∈ L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $∥h∥_1 ≤ ∥f∥_1 · ∥g∥_1.$

So I have done everything on this problem but show that $h(x)$ is actually defined a.e.  I don't think showing $\|h\|_1$ is finite is enough, is it?  Thanks.

Comment: "I don't think showing $\|h\|_1$ is finite is enough, is it?" If you do it the usual way, it pretty much is. All you need to add are a few words how the a.e. definedness of $h$ follows from that.

Comment: I guess my question is how do we know that $h(x)$ is measurable?

Comment: 1. $(x,y) \mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is measurable. 2. Tonelli. 3. Fubini.